# Image saved with imwrite() with lossless mode is not visible

Tags: image, matlab, jpeg

I want to save my image as JPEG so I used `imwrite` function in MATLAB. But because JPEG follows lossy format, I am not getting exact intensity values when the file is saved as .jpg

I tried

```
imwrite(a, 'a.jpg', 'Mode', 'lossless');
```

So I got the exact intensity values but the image is not visible in respective folder. It is visible only in the MATLAB environment.

I must save my image in JPEG format only. So please suggest me any other alternative to save image as JPEG which can save image with same intensity values.

Comment: Tags are very important to reach the right audience that can help you. If you have a MATLAB question, you should tag it with the MATLAB tag, not the C tag. I have fixed the tags for you.

Comment: I have tried replicating your problem. I do get a `a.jpg` file, and when I open it in a standard image viewer program it shows the image saved. However, Finder (this is the Mac equivalent of the Windows Explorer) does not show a preview of the image. Please >[edit]< your question and include information about what operating system you are using, and in what way you're not seeing the image (do you see the file, but without a preview, like I do, can you see the image when opening it in Photoshop or equivalent program, or do you not see the file itself ?).

Comment: Lossless JPEG is relatively poorly supported. You may have to consider another lossless format such as PNG, or NetPBM PPM/PAM format.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I've just hit the same problem. On Windows 10, the files will not open in MS Photos (`We can't open this file`) or gimp (`JPEG image plug-In could not open image...Unsupported JPEG process: SOF type 0xc3`). If OP absolutely must use JPEG, then they can look around for a program that supports reading lossless jpeg, or minimise loss by setting the quality to 100.

Comment: Hello Cris Luengo sir, I am using Windows 7 operating system.

Answer (score 0):

The basic issue is that despite the fact that the image was saved correctly, no image viewer recognizes the lossless format. It seems to be the original jpeg format that nobody uses today because of the poorer compression (better than BMP but poorer than lossy jpeg). I assume you must use jpeg because some software or website you use need this format, but it will most likely not decode lossless correctly. jpeg loses data, I don't see a way around it.

Comment: I am working with tampering issue  and try to solve the issue using watermarking. During watermark embedding, i do modification within image's pixel intensity values which i need back when I want to extract the data. But in between these two, I have to save the file as '.jpg' , when I am using imwrite() it will change my pixel values. This change affects during my extraction process.  Is there any solution of my problem?